# Gas required exceeds limit: 3000000.

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract createNewToken {
    uint256 total_ether_to_send;
    address private owner;

    //constructor
    function createNewToken() public{
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    // client request for tokens by sending ether.
    function requestForToken() public payable{
        address sender = msg.sender;
        uint value = msg.value;
        total_ether_to_send = value;
        require(sender.balance >= total_ether_to_send);
        owner.transfer(total_ether_to_send);

        total_ether_to_send = value / 2;
        require(owner.balance >= total_ether_to_send);
        sender.transfer(total_ether_to_send);
    } 
}
```

I have written this code in solidity in Remix IDE. The contract was successfully created but when I used it, it gave me an error saying  **"Gas required exceeds limit: 3000000.  An important gas estimation might also be the sign of a problem in the contract code. Please check loops and be sure you did not sent value to a non payable function".** I don't have much code written but its still gave me this error. Can anyone help?

Comment: This question would better fit in ethereum.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, your `msg.value` is already sent to your method, hence you don't need to check senders balance: `require(sender.balance >= total_ether_to_send);`.

**Second**, you don't have a fallback function in your contract to receive ether.

**Third**, you are trying to send 100% `msg.value` to owner and then send 50% of `msg.value` back to sender. Obviously you cannot spend 150% of msg.value without any additional funds on your contract. Here is example of working code:

```
function requestForToken() public payable{
    address sender = msg.sender;
    uint value = msg.value;
    total_ether_to_send = value / 2;
    require(this.balance >= total_ether_to_send);
    owner.transfer(total_ether_to_send);

    require(this.balance >= total_ether_to_send);
    sender.transfer(total_ether_to_send);
} 

function() payable {}
```

Comment: I got your first and second but couldn't accept third. How its 150%. First I excepted 100% and then returned 50% back (lets say as discount).

I wanted to write a contract in which I accept ethers and provide them with my tokens.I think I had to write these type of lines. I also tried some thing like this
    <b> total_ether_to_send = msg.value token_name / token_symbol </b>
but this doesn't work though I had created a new token. I want to send some tokens in exchange to some ethers.

So I started with this type of code but they didn't worked as well. Can you help with how to send tokens

Comment: @Harsh you are sending 100% of msg.value to owner from your smart contract. After this operation there is 0% of msg.value available at your contract and you are still trying to send 50% of msg.value. Think of it as sender sent 100 wei to your contract. You transfer 100 wei from contract to owner. After it you try to send 50 wei from contract to sender when contract already has 0 balance.

Comment: Got it but doesn't sender.transfer(50) will again sent back money from owner account. Or it will use contract account.

If it is from contract account than how do I sent it from owner account to sender. 

And what about sending tokens.

Thanks for the reply. Thanks a lot. @Roman

Comment: @Harsh it will use contract’s balance. If you want to make a 50% off discount, just give 2x more tokens to sender. Btw to send tokens in crowdsale you can use e.g. `balances[msg.sender] += msg.value / tokenPrice`, where `tokenPrice` is in wei.